# docker container has no access to localhost webhook

Tags: docker, docker-compose, graphql, localhost, webhooks

I'm working on our webhook locally before building a docker container, and want my (Linux) container to communicate with it, using `host.docker.internal:ping`.
It had been working before, but lately, for some reason, I'm getting this error from our `graphql-engine`, Hasura:

```
    { 
   "timestamp":"2019-11-05T18:45:32.860+0000",
   "level":"error",
   "type":"webhook-log",
   "detail":{ 
      "response":null,
      "url":"http://host.docker.internal:3000/simple/webhook",
      "method":"GET",
      "http_error":{ 
         "type":"http_exception",
         "message":"ConnectionFailure Network.Socket.getAddrInfo (called with preferred socket type/protocol: AddrInfo {addrFlags = [AI_ADDRCONFIG], addrFamily = AF_UNSPEC, addrSocketType = Stream, addrProtocol = 0, addrAddress = <assumed to be undefined>, addrCanonName = <assumed to be undefined>}, host name: Just \"host.docker.internal\", service name: Just \"3000\"): does not exist (Temporary failure in name resolution)"
      },
      "status_code":null
   }
}
```

Here's my docker compose:

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  postgres:  
    image: postgres:11.2  
    restart: always  
    ports:  
      - 5432:5432  
    volumes:  
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data  
    environment:  
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres  
      - POSTGRES_USER=...  
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=...  

  graphql-engine:  
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:latest  
    depends_on:  
      - postgres  
    restart: always  
    environment:  
      - HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://...:...@postgres:5432/postgres  
      - HASURA_GRAPHQL_ACCESS_KEY=...  
      - HASURA_GRAPHQL_AUTH_HOOK=http://host.docker.internal:3000/simple/webhook  
    command:  
      - graphql-engine  
      - serve  
      - --enable-console  
    ports:  
      - 8080:8080  
       volumes:   
  postgres:   
  data:
```

The local project is for sure working and listening to port 3000. Nontheless, it isn't receiving any requests [as it should] from the graphql-engine container. Could it be related to our proxy?

Comment: What's your host OS?  (`host.docker.internal` doesn't work on native Linux hosts.)

Comment: Thanks for helping, it's Windows 10. Note that it used to work this way in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemed to be an issue with Docker Desktop.
Uninstalled the whole docker environment and rebuilt it all, that fixed it.